# OP_JMP opcode scalability

Tags: lua

My app uses a customized version of Lua 5.0.2 and some customers feed very large (automatically generated) scripts into it. For example, scripts that are 200 megabytes or more in size. It all seems to work fine but I'm wondering how scalable the Lua VM is.

I'm especially concerned about the `OP_JMP` scalability. In Lua 5.0.2 `OP_JMP` uses 18 bits to code the destination PC. So it can jump 262144 instructions at a maximum. Can this limitation be a problem with very large scripts? For example, a 200 megabyte script in which a function at the very bottom of the script calls a function at the very top of the script? Will this hit an `OP_JMP` limit or are function calls implemented in a different way and `OP_JMP` is only used for coding control structures like `for`, `if`, ... which are very unlikely to have to jump more than `2^18` instructions...

Thanks to anybody who can shed some light onto this!

Comment: OP_JMP is only used for coding control structures like "for", "if".  The limit on number of constants in a function will be a more realistic surprise for you.  You can also stumble upon limitation on number of local variables in a function (it is less than 255).  Frankly speaking, Lua is not very suitable for large automatically-generated scripts.  Lua is for people, not for machines.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, Since 1.0 Lua was designed to load large automatically-generated scripts. Only at that time they weren't so large. Current versions of Lua can load very large scripts.

Comment: @lhf - Very large scripts with limit of 255 local variables in a block?  It's not serious for automatically generated code.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, I meant, very large data scripts (= mostly static tables)